# Getting invalid dataype when creating table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I added a column in a table called FACILITY. Then, I tried to CREATE a table called CLUBMANAGER, and am greeted with the message:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

My SQL statements are:

```
CREATE TABLE FACILITY(
facilityName    VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
rate            NUMBER(7,2),
status          VARCHAR2(25),
CONSTRAINT FACILITY_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(facilityName) );

ALTER TABLE FACILITY ADD MANAGER_EMAIL VARCHAR2(100);
ALTER TABLE facility ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fac UNIQUE (manager_email);
CREATE TABLE CLUBMANAGER (
    email       VARCHAR2(100)   NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR2(100)   NOT NULL,
    phoneNum    NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  CLUBMANAGER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (email),
    CONSTRAINT  CLUBMEMBER_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES FACILITY (MANAGER_EMAIL));
```

Line 2 was:

```
email       VARCHAR2(100)   NOT NULL
```

My SQL Output is:

```
    SQL> ALTER TABLE facility ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fac UNIQUE (manager_email);

Table altered.

SQL> CREATE TABLE CLUBMANAGER (
  2  emailVARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
  3  nameVARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
  4  phoneNumNUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
  5  CONSTRAINTCLUBMANAGER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (email),
  6  CONSTRAINTCLUBMEMBER_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES FACILITY (MANAGER_EMAIL));
emailVARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
            *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

I am using Oracle Database XE 11.2.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70c26c453e9f19903f90e49e676e80fe - check here it works both for varchar and varchar2

Comment: you need spaces between column names and data types and constraints such as `email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posted, there's no *invalid datatype* (at least, I don't see any), but missing primary or unique key - you can't create a foreign key constraint which doesn't point to one of those keys.

Have a look: first, a *dummy* `FACILITY` table, altered as you did it:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE facility (id NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE facility ADD manager_email VARCHAR2 (100);

Table altered.
```

Create table `CLUBMANAGER`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE clubmanager
  2  (
  3     email      VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  4     name       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  5     phonenum   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
  6     CONSTRAINT clubmanager_pkey PRIMARY KEY (email),
  7     CONSTRAINT clubmember_fkey FOREIGN KEY
  8        (email)
  9         REFERENCES facility (manager_email)
 10  );
       REFERENCES facility (manager_email)
                            *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Nope, won't work. Add a unique key and crate `CLUBMANAGER` once again:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE facility ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fac UNIQUE (manager_email);

Table altered.

SQL> CREATE TABLE clubmanager
  2  (
  3     email      VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  4     name       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  5     phonenum   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
  6     CONSTRAINT clubmanager_pkey PRIMARY KEY (email),
  7     CONSTRAINT clubmember_fkey FOREIGN KEY
  8        (email)
  9         REFERENCES facility (manager_email)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

As you see, everything is OK. If it still doesn't work at your side, please, post your own SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: I've followed your steps, and made manager_email unique. I tried running the CREATE statement again, and am greeted with the same error. I've posted the edits on top.

Comment: I ran your code (Oracle 11g), no problem whatsoever. But, look how error report looks like: `emailVARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,` - no space at all. Did you, by any chance, write that query in MS Word (or some similar text editor)? Try to type the command directly into SQL*Plus, don't copy/paste it from somewhere else.

Comment: I typed the query in Notepad++. I'm supposed to make a script, and run that script on Oracle. Even with the script, it shows the same error.

Comment: OK. Just to make sure, please, type everything into SQL*Plus - actually, you don't even have to type everything, just `CREATE TABLE CLUBMANAGER (email VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL);`

Comment: I found the problem. I was using TAB to make a space between words. Apparently Oracle doesn't notice TAB as a space. After deleting the TAB and adding a space, it works fine. Thanks for your constant help!

Comment: You're welcome. Huh, TAB ... right; it *looks* OK, but it is misleading. I'm glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting you to get `ORA-00902`.

> EDIT : you need spaces between column names and data types and
>   constraints such as `email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL` instead of `emailVARCHAR(100)NOT NULL`

The column `MANAGER_EMAIL` needs to be a `unique` or `primary key` as being able to be referenced by a `foreign key` .

So, use `ALTER TABLE FACILITY ADD MANAGER_EMAIL VARCHAR2(100) primary key [unique] ;`